# How can I construct a vim mapping to perform Ctrl-N, but as if iskeyword included '-'?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, autocomplete

In Vim, when I'm programming, I often want Ctrl-N to behave as if `-` were part of a keyword; in other words, have it included in `iskeyword`. However, I'd like to create a new keymapping for this and have Ctrl-N keep it's existing behavior.

I've tried this:

```
inoremap <C-B> <C-O>:set iskeyword+=-<CR><C-N>
```

... which sort of works, but the iskeyword option includes the extra `-` afterward, which isn't desired behavior.

This also sort of works:

```
inoremap <C-B> <C-O>:set iskeyword+=-<CR><C-N><C-O>:set iskeyword-=-<CR>
```

... but the pop-up menu is killed by the `<C-O>`.

Is there a way I can have my cake and eat it? Have the pop-up menu from  appear and remain in place, but also set `iskeyword` back to what it was afterward?

Alternatively, is there another way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work.

```
function! CustomComplete(type)
    set iskeyword+=-
    return a:type
endfunction
inoremap <expr> <C-B> CustomComplete("<C-N>")
autocmd CompleteDone * set iskeyword-=-
```

We use an expression mapping to run the function which sets `iskeyword` every time its run (doesn't seem to be a problem. I also didn't find a autocmd for before ins-completion.) The return value of the function is then used as the replacement for the mapping. In this case you wanted `<C-N>` behavior. Then to remove set `-` from set iskeyword we use the `CompleteDone` autocomand which happens after ins-completion is finished.

---

Also I tried both of your mappings the first one doesn't really work as expected since it also has `<C-O>` which kills the completion window.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! - that seems to work. The insight here was using the wrapper function around `C-N` (which I didn't know you could do), and the `CompleteDone` event. Thank you - wouldn't have figured this out myself!